# Connecting Visual Studio Code to a Codeanywhere container

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, codeanywhere

I use Codeanywhere. The cloud IDE is okay but I'd rather use Visual Studio Code. Since I'm on a work computer without admin rights, I have a portable version of Visual Studio Code that I'd like to use to connect to my CodeAnywhere container. I found a couple of extensions that let you mount a folder through ssh. They are SSH FS and FS Remote. But I can't figure out how to actually connect. Anyone have any experience with this? Or know any alternatives to hosting a container remotely and connect with VSC code? Thanks

Comment: From time to time I use the [SSH FS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs) extension, but only to access and modify some files on a few servers. I'm not sure if you're able to use it to connect to your container since this extension just mounts a remote folder over SSH as a local workspace folder.

Answer (score 3):

The following are instructions from a Mac.

**Setting up SSH keys**

1. Open a terminal.
2. Run the command to generate the SSH keys: **ssh-keygen -t rsa**
3. Hit enter to accept the default location to save the key.
4. Hit enter twice when prompted for entering passphrase.
5. Copy the public key: **pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**
6. Open an SSH session on your Codeanywhere container.
7. Paste your copied public key to the file **~/.ssh/authorized_keys** on the container.

**Gather Container Information**

1. Right-click the container and select **Info**.
2. You'll get an information page specifically for your container such as host and port.

**Setting up Visual Studio Code**

1. Install **Remote - SSH** extension by Microsoft for Visual Studio Code.
2. Click on the button at the left bottom corner of VSC, which will open the command palette with a list of Remote-SSH options.
3. Select **Open Configuration File...**
4. Select the ssh config file to edit, example */Users/username/.ssh/config*
5. Add the following, but fill in the info for your container:

```
Host Codeanywhere
    HostName hostXX.codeanyhost.com
    User cabox
    Port 12345
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

6. Save and exit the config file.
7. Again, open the command palette for Remote-SSH and select **Connect to Host**.